# Woocommerce hide prefix on product page

Tags: woocommerce, hide, product, categories

I used snippet for adding prefix before price. It is working nice, but I would like to have it showed only on category product page.

I would like to hide prefix on simple product page.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Used snippet:

```
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_get_price_html’, ‘njengah_text_before_price’ );

function njengah_text_before_price($price){

global $post;

$product_id = $post->ID;

$product_array = array( 25338 );//add in the product IDs to add text after price

if ( in_array( $product_id, $product_array )) {

$text_to_add_before_price = ‘ Cena od ‘; //change text in bracket to your preferred text

return $text_to_add_before_price . $price ;

}else{

return $price;
}

}
```